# GCP app engine connect to GCP cloud SQL

Tags: mysql, xampp, phpmyadmin, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

follow these steps https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/phpmyadmin-on-app-engine

I open the service to connect cloud SQL, and type the password.

It shows

```
#2006 - MySQL server has gone away
mysqli_real_connect(): MySQL server has gone away
mysqli_real_connect(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=-1
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2006): MySQL server has gone away
```

But using xampp' phpmyadmin I can connect.

I think it depend on http
because my service only can use https:// to connect cloud SQL,
use http:// to connect  cloud SQL, it will show nothing

But XAMPP (which uses http:// to connect to cloud SQL) can log in.

Can somebody help me? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solve it.I change the wrong directory..

phpmyadmin has more than one phpmyadmin directory

ex:/usr/share/phpmyadmin .. and /etc/phpmyadmin

I change the /etc/phpmyadmin and it works!